# Draggables in react-beautiful-dnd don't dragging but only create a placeholder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-beautiful-dnd

My simple app to practise with react-beautiful-dnd fails to work as expected. The list items don't drag rather just create an adjacent placeholder. I read that margins on the draggable has unintended consequences but getting rid of the bootstrap styles still doesn't improve matters.
Here is the app: https://codesandbox.io/s/53j0kvnw14

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `provided.draggableProps.style` in the `Draggable` component

`style={{ maxWidth: 400, ...provided.draggableProps.style }}`

see https://codesandbox.io/s/2p0k6mjo4y

Comment: Your link doesn't seem to work, but your solution sure did end my 14+ hours of misery and now works like a charm. Cheers